# Installing wget in Debian 10

Tags: debian, wget

I just moved from Ubuntu to Debian 10, and I haven't been able to install wget. I tried

```
sudo apt-get install wget
```

But recived this message:

```
This may mean that the package is missing, obsolete or only find available from some other source. The wget package is not available, but some other package references to it.
```

Comment: What is reported by `apt-cache policy wget`?

Answer (score 2):

This happens if you boot a live image:

[image: Screenshot]

Fix it by running `sudo apt update` to update package information first.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not running in a live image, this happens because of missing entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Simply add another entry:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
```

I'm kind of confused why this is not there by default but I suspect is has something to do with the mirror option in the installer.